# How do I pass a component as prob to a grandchild in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering how to pass down a Component as a prob to a Grandchild in React?
My approach is the following but i can't quite figure it out. What's best practice in such a case?

```
const SomeComp = () => (
  <span> hello from comp </span>
)

const Parent = () => { 
  return (
    <Child componentToPassDown={<SomeComp />}  />
  )
}

const Child = ({ componentToPassDown }) => { 
  return (
    <>
     {/* This would render <SomeComp /> in Child, but It shall be rendered in Grandchild: /*} 
     {componentToPassDown}
     <GrandChild anotherPassDown={?} />


    </>
  )
}
const GrandChild = ({?}) => {
  return (
    {render SomeComp here}  
  )
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it and i am ashamed.
For future reference if anybody got the same 'problem': You just pass it down one more time.

```
const Child = ({ componentToPassDown }) => { 
  return (    
     <GrandChild anotherPassDown={componentToPassDown } />
  )
}
const GrandChild = ({anotherPassDown}) => {
  return (
    {anotherPassDown}  
  )
}
```